# Redirecting to an action in the same controller doesn't work - CakePHP 3.x

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

CakePHP 3.5.13

According to the [documentation](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers.html#redirecting-to-another-action-on-the-same-controller):

> If you need to forward the current action to a different action on the same controller, you can use `Controller::setAction()` to update the request object, modify the view template that will be rendered and forward execution to the named action:

```
// From a delete action, you can render the updated
// list page.
$this->setAction('index');
```

But this doesn't seem to work.

For example, in my controller I have 2 functions, `index()` and `apply_filters()`. I want to redirect the user back to `index()` after `apply_filters()` has been executed.

So I've done this:

```
public function apply_filters()
{
    $this->autoRender = false;

    // code for applying filters
    $this->setAction('index');
}

public function index()
{
    debug('index');
}
```

`apply_filters()` does not have a view, so `$this->autoRender = false;`

When the user is on the URL `/apply-filters` it simply stays there without redirecting back to `index()`.

It works absolutely fine if I replace `$this->setAction('index')` with `return $this->redirect(['controller' => 'Front', 'action' => 'index']);`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Forwarding (internally redirecting)* is not the same as *HTTP redirecting*.

The two methods do two different things, one forwards the call as described, changing the application state in a way that the action where the call is being forwarded to, thinks that it was the one that was called to begin with, and the other creates an HTTP redirect response.

If you want the latter, then `redirect()` is what you are looking for, not `setAction()`.

See also

- **[API > \Cake\Controller\Controller::setAction()](https://api.cakephp.org/3.5/class-Cake.Controller.Controller.html#_setAction)**
- **[API > \Cake\Controller\Controller::redirect()](https://api.cakephp.org/3.5/class-Cake.Controller.Controller.html#_redirect)**